Horror movie that had flying steel balls with built-in knives
I remember in my childhood I watched a horror movie that completely terrified me. Some details I can remember:

There were flying steel balls that had knives embedded. They attacked people in groups. Some character, if not mistaken, shot one of such balls down and carried along with him.
Some of the villains looked like dead men walking.
In the end of the movie I think, there was some kind of Dracula-alike villain that stayed in creo camera. 


Sound like it could be the movie "Phantasm" (1979).

The residents of a small town have begun dying under strange circumstances, leading young Mike (Michael Baldwin) to investigate. After discovering that the Tall Man (Angus Scrimm), the town's mortician, is killing and reanimating the dead as misshapen zombies, Mike seeks help from his older brother, Jody (Bill Thornbury), and local ice cream man Reggie (Reggie Bannister). Working together, they try to lure out and kill the Tall Man, all the while avoiding his minions and a deadly silver sphere.

Scene showing one of the flying spheres in the trailer.

Yes, that's it thank you!
